# Firebase storage uploading broken image

Tags: angularjs, image, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a cropped image using [this cropper](https://github.com/AllanBishop/angular-img-cropper). It is returning a `base64` version of the cropped image.

I am trying to convert that `base64` image to a `blob` or a `file` to be able to upload it to `firebase storage` using the code below.

```
var imageBase64 = $scope.cropper.croppedImage.split(',')[1];
var blob = new Blob([imageBase64], {type: 'image/png'});
var file = new File([imageBase64], 'imageFileName2.png', {type: 'image/png'});
```

when I tried to print `file` it has created an acutal `File` object that looks like this.

```
{
    lastModified:1471604365544,
    lastModifiedDate:"Fri Aug 19 2016 18:59:25 GMT+0800 (PHT)",
    name:"imageFileName2.png",
    size:228808,
    type:"image/png",
    webkitRelativePath:""
}
```

The `File` is being uploaded successfully though, but the result is broken. The preview on the `firebase storage` dashboard just looks like this (it never stops loading, and when I tried to download it, I got a broken image) :

[image]

To prove that my `base64` image is not broken, here's a `base64` pic of my cat [Akasha](http://pastebin.com/HTJfQe79), you can preview it in this [base64 viewer](http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter).

Answer (score 0):

In the 3.3.0 JS client, you can just upload a `base64` string ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_string))!

```
var imageBase64 = $scope.cropper.croppedImage.split(',')[1];
ref.putString(imageBase64, 'base64').then(function(snapshot) {
  console.log('Uploaded a base64 string!');
});
```

The `Blob` and `File` APIs both take a `UInt8Array`, which the `base64` string isn't, so you were basically creating an array that contained a single item, which was the `base64` string, which wasn't a valid blob. Use the above upload to solve the problem.

Comment: how can we do it with blob type like  var imageBlob = new Blob([new Uint8Array([success])], { type: "image/jpeg" });

Comment: @Ozi see the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_blob_or_file, use `ref.put(imageBlob)`.